# Redirect a state to default substate with Router in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-router

What's the correct way of having **default substate** in new Angular2 Router?

for example I want router

```
/user
```

redirects to

```
/user/profile
```

like a default substate of user state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **redirectTo** as shown below.

When user tries to navigate to *www.domain.com/user* because of **redirectTo**, he will be redirected to *www.domain.com/user/profile*.

```
import { Routes,RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

let routes: Routes = [
  { path: '/user', redirectTo: '/user/profile', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '/user/profile', component:somecomponent },  
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```